# How to conditionally choose tag and its attributes in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to render component as either `div` is no `href` was provided or `Link`. Here is my code:

```
  const Comp = href ? Link : 'div';
  return (
    <Comp
      href={href + '/' + node.text}
    >...</Comp>
)
```

It works but it always render `href` even if its `undefined` and hence its `div` component. How can I fix it? I can't put `null` on `href` because it shouts that it must be string

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const Comp = href ? Link : 'div';
const props = href ? { href: href + '/' + node.text } : {};

  return (
    <Comp
      {...props}
    ></Comp>
)
```